# Progess bar control old style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working with a **Progress Bar Control** but I need to use the old style of windows one like we have bars in [progress bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/progress-bar-control) first one:

> The following illustration shows a progress bar using visual styles. The appearance of the control will vary depending on the operating system

But it has to be independent of the os help me with the right direction

Comment: Just create your own, create a custom control add Min, Max, Current properties and animate to your liking.

Comment: Do you have a sample?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you! feel free to modify it to your needs!

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Value" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" MinWidth="10" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Maximum}" Height="50">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Column="0" Width="{TemplateBinding Value}">


                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It is a very basic style but a good base to start from. If you are not familiar with styles, to make this work just place this code inside the `<Window.Resources>` Tags of your Window

Comment: Hi this was not displaying the bars it just displaying the progress in blue clour

Comment: i this case you have to do the work yourself by creating a custom control adding the bars and displaing them one by one
this style will make your progressbar look the same on all systems as you asked for 
but making you a custom control that looks the way you want it to be exceeds the limits of this question

Comment: ok np you took the grid to display progress  which control i can use for bars that will be fine

Comment: you could use a uniform grid, with one row containing grids, with a small margin... but thats a messy way to achive it.
You dont want the bars to slowly appear from left to right, but to be there or not right?
That will not work with that style